# Can Chef AWS cookbook query EC2 instance tags?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, chef

Chef has the official AWS cookbook (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws), which allows for spinning up of AWS resources, as well as updating of resource tags.

Can the custom resources introduced by the AWS cookbook be used within recipes to READ the AWS resource tags? The only resources listed in help docs are used to update/create/delete those tags.

My goal is to be able to determine the Chef environment based on a specific AWS tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same method that is used by the tag LWRP.  Take a look at https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws/blob/master/providers/resource_tag.rb#L90-L92

```
ec2.describe_tags(:filters => { 'resource-id' => @current_resource.resource_id }).map do |tag|   
  chef-environment = tag[:my_tag_name]
end
```

Something like that ^^